# how to write two string and their two variables values using 1 Console.Writeline() in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I am switched to c# and want to write two variable value in one line using Console.Writeline() function in c#.

In c++ i could have done it like this:

```
cout<<"symbol : "<<symbol<<"frequency : "<<frequency<<endl;
```

which will print :

```
symbol : a frequency : 10
```

I tried to do in c# but it just print only first variable, I done like this :

```
 Console.WriteLine("Symbol : " +parentNode.symbol ,"frequency is : " + code );
```

which just print only `symbol : 10` **don't print frequency**.

I tried to two Console.WriteLine() for both but that change the line.

Any help how to achieve so ?

Comment: sorry ? i couldn't understand ?

Comment: you've used a `,` instead of a `+` after your `parentNode.symbol`. Does it solve your problem ? By the way, if you want to do it on the same line you can use `Console.Write()` for both of your `strings`, and it won't change the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I think you're trying to achieve can be done like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : " + parentNode.symbol + " frequency is : " + code);
```

i.e. `Console.WriteLine(string)`

But a better way would be to use the following overload `Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0} frequency is : {1}", parentNode.symbol, code);
```

And as of C# 6, you can use string interpolation (note the `$` before the string):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Symbol : {parentNode.symbol} frequency is : {code}");
```

The problem is that your code is using the second overload of `Console.WriteLine` but your code is not written in a way that this method can understand it.

For more information, see the MSDN documentation on the [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console.WriteLine(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

- [`Console.WriteLine(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: error CS0117: `System.Console' does not contain a definition for `Writeline'
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

Comment: Ah slight mis-casing in my answer - just to keep you on your toes :P Corrected now.

Comment: what changes did you made ? i couldn't identify yet ?

Comment: @user234839 If you click [`edited TIME ago`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22354256/revisions) in a question it lets you see differences.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a syntax error with the placement of your comma. My guess is you meant to place it inside the string, to separate "symbol" and "frequency". Then you'd need an additional `+` sign to concatenate the strings.

---

Try this instead. You can specify place-holders in your string, then specify the arguments that will replace them afterwards:

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}, frequency is : {1}", parentNode.symbol, code);
```

It's a little easier to tell what the final output will look like, too.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `"+"`

```
 Console.WriteLine("Symbol : " +parentNode.symbol  + "frequency is : " + code );
                                                  ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways.  First, you can use `.Write()` instead of `.WriteLine()` so as to not include a carriage return:

```
Console.Write("Symbol : " + parentNode.symbol);
Console.WriteLine("frequency is : " + code);
```

Or perhaps you can just concatenate the strings together in one call:

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : " + parentNode.symbol + " frequency is : " + code);
```

The *reason* your attempt didn't work was because the overload for `Console.WriteLine()` accepts a format string and any number of objects which can be converted to a string and placed within the format string.  However, your first argument was a string without formatting placeholders, so the second argument was essentially ignored.

You can make use of formatting strings with something like this, which is generally preferred over the above options:

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0} frequency is : {1}", parentNode.symbol, code);
```

In this case the method call has three arguments, the first of which is the format string (with placeholders) and the next two are objects which can be converted to strings to put in those placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

You should have written

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : " + parentNode.symbol + "frequency is : " + code );
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : " +parentNode.symbol ,"frequency is : " + code );
```

as `WriteLine()` expects a format in first argument and parameters for format or a string.

Another way to get this done would be

```
Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0} frequency is {1}", parentNode.symbol, code );
```

as pointed out by another answers.